# d3.js nvd3.js with phonegap android blank

Tags: android, cordova, d3.js

using phonegap, I am trying to build a visualization app for android 4.4.  I have some d3 based charts which work fine from pc browser(chrome).   however the apk that phone gap generates runs but is blank.   I have tried numerous types of charts.

Any ideas...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some kind of bug with phonegap,

when I build the apk locally using the cordova cli tools,  the output apk works just fine,

any thoughts?,

Comment: I have the same problem when using Ionic, suggesting it could be Cordova related. All the other chart types seem to work fine.